# Como mudar o valor de uma variável?

Tags: r

Gostaria de saber como faço para mudar o valor de uma variável. Tenho uma variável numérica e gostaria de mudá-la para uma character.

Answer (score 3):

Se a variável numérica chama `x`, faça

```
x <- as.character(x)
```

Answer (score 1):

Iago, tudo bem?

O R não exige declaração de variável, então basta você atribuir diretamente o valor character desejado. Faça o teste aí:

```
x <- 0
class(x)

x <- "Hello world"
class(x)
```